# GridStackJs attributes not working in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, gridstack

I am applying  data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="3" attributes of **GridStackJS**  in html page of my Ember.Js project but it is not working.

```
<div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="3">
```

I have used js files and css files of GridStack and it is loading properly in network. On dragging any element it is moving properly but on loosing mouse control is coming back to its original position. I think it is because of it is not able to detect is position which is achieved using **data-gs-xx** attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear to me, but it seems that you don't apply jquery plugin in a proper way.

[ember-cli guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#javascript-assets) explains how to manage dependencies, in case if you don't know.

[ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code) explains how to use component to integrate jquery plugin with ember.